# Estimate $H_3$ with a Polynomial - Ax^2 + Bx + C

Tags: numerical-methods, least-squares, estimation

I have the Inner product: $ <f, f> = \sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)^2 \cdot e^{-x^2}}$

and I want to estimate $H_3 = 8x^3 - 12x$ with a function $g(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$  such that the norm $|| H_3(x) - g(x) ||$is minimal.

I tackled it with Least squares method - I Chose the Hermite Polynomials as a base because they are orthogonal with this given inner product, so I get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}<H_0,H_0>&<H_0,H_1>&<H_0,H_2>\\ <H1,H_0>&<H_1,H1>&<H1,H_2>\\ <H2,H_0>&<H2,H1>&<H2,H2>\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}<f,H_0>\\ <f,H_1>\\ <f,H_2>\end{pmatrix} $$

and since $ f(x) = H_3(x) $ I get that the right side of the equation is the zero vector ($\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H_n H_m e^{-x^2}dx ~ =~ C_n~\delta_{nm}$ where $C_n$ is just some number). and since:

$a, b, c = 0, 0,0$

But that doesn't make sense (to me) that the best estimation of $H_3$ is the zero Polynomial.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: There exists u,v,w such that $g=uH_0+vH_1+wH_2$ and $||H_3-g||^2=||-uH_0-vH_1-wH_2+H_3||^2=u^2C_0+v^2C_1+w^2C_2+C_3$ and by minimizing u=v=w=0.